# ViewComponent and InvokeAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

In the following method I'm getting the **warning**: `This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously`. Where can I use `await` in this mehod? **Note**: This method is returning a simple static View without interacting with a Database etc.

```
public class TestViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since you have no asynchronous work to do, you could remove the `async` qualifier and just return `Task.FromResult`:

```
public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
  return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View());
}
```

Alternatively, you could just ignore the warning (i.e., turn it off with a `#pragma`).

Comment: Is there any performance difference in using `return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View())` vs. just ignoring the warning?

Comment: @nam: I *suspect* `FromResult` would be faster, but it's completely negligible in this case.

Comment: Thank you for providing some reasoning for your solution - it works.