# ViewComponent InvokeAsync method and non async operation

Tags: asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

In asp.net core `ViewComponent` we have to implement logic in an `InvokeAsync` method that returns an `IViewComponentResult`. However I do not have any `async` logic to perform inside the invoke method. So based on [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007669/viewcomponent-and-invokeasync-method) I have removed the `async` qualifier and just return `Task.FromResult`

```
public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(MyBaseModel model)
{        
    var name = MyFactory.GetViewComponent(model.DocumentTypeID);        
    return Task.FromResult<IViewComponentResult>(View(name, model));
}
```

and then in View ( since I don't have `async` I am not using `await` here)

```
@Component.InvokeAsync("MyViewComponent", new { model = Model })
```

However view renders this:

`System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must `await` the `Component.InvokeAsync`. The fact that your method doesn't do anything async doesn't matter. The method itself is async.

However, that's a bit of an oversimplification. Frankly, the ease of the `async`/`await` keywords belies how complicated all this actually is. To be accurate, instead of calling these types of methods "async", it's more appropriate to discuss them as "task-returning". A task is essentially a handle for some operation. That operation could be async *or* sync. It's most closely associated with async, simply because wrapping sync operations in a task would be pretty pointless in most scenarios. However, the point is that just because something must return a task does not also imply that it *must* be async.

All async does is allow the *possibility* of a thread switch. In scenarios where there's some operation, typically involving I/O, that would cause the working thread to be idle for some period of time, the thread becomes available to be used for other work, and the original work *may* complete on a different thread. Notice the use of the passive language here. Async operations can involve no thread switching; the task could complete on the same thread, as if it was sync. The task could even complete immediately, if the underlying operation has already completed.

In your scenario here, you're not doing any async work, which is fine. However, the method definition requires `Task<T>` as the return, so you must use `Task.FromResult` to return your actual result. That's all pretty standard stuff, and seems to be understood already by you. What you're missing, I think, is that you're thinking that since you're not actually doing any asynchronous work, it would be wrong to utilize `await`. There's nothing magical about the `await` keyword; it basically just means hold here until the task completes. If there's no async work to be done, as is the case here, the sync code will just run as normal and yield back to the calling code when done, However, as a convenience, `await` also performs one other vital function: it unwraps the task.

That is where your problem lies. Since you're not awaiting, the task itself is being returned into the Razor view processing pipeline. It doesn't know what to do with that, so it does what it does by default and just calls `ToString` on it, hence the text you're getting back. Unwrapped, you'd just have `IViewComponentResult` and Razor *does* know what to do with that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, adding the `await` keyword worked

Answer (score 1):

If your logic performed inside the invoke method is synchronous, i.e., you don't have any `await`, you have 2 options:

1. You can define invoke method without `async` keyword and it should return `Task.FromResult<T>`
2. Use `public IViewComponentResult Invoke()` instead.

I think the `async` keyword enables the `await` keyword and that's pretty much about it. Nothing special about `async` keyword.

On the main thread where your view is getting rendered, since the tag helper method 
 to invoke a view component `Component.InvokeAsync()` is awaitable, you do need to put `await` keyword there to start the task. `await` examines the view component rendering to see if it has already completed. If it has, then the main thread just keeps going. Otherwise the main thread will tell the ViewComponent to run.